# Application is not stopped with missingTopicFatal and manually started listeners

Tags: spring, spring-kafka

I'm using spring and spring-kafka.

When the application starts, I'm loading compacted topics into memory then when the topics are fully read, the application is started.

In order to do that I created `@KafkaListeners` with autostartup to false and a `SmartLifeCycle` bean with `AbstractMessageListenerContainer.DEFAULT_PHASE - 1` phase which is doing `listener.start()` on all those listeners (which read compacted topics) then wait for them to be finished.

This is working great but if I set `spring.kafka.listener.missing-topics-fatal = true` with a missing topic, there is an error :

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Topic(s) [mytopic] is/are not present and missingTopicsFatal is true

It's the expected behavior, but the application is not shutdown, my manually started listeners keeps running and sending errors :

java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@502e1410 has not been refreshed yet

How can I make the application exit in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch the exception and shut down the JVM:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So60036945Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SpringApplication.run(So60036945Application.class, args);
        }
        catch (ApplicationContextException ace) {
            if (ace.getCause() instanceof IllegalStateException) {
                ace.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }


    @KafkaListener(id = "so60036945", topics = "so60036945a")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

But, as I said in Gitter, it's better to auto-start the compacted topic listeners and start the other listeners manually (the other way around to what you are doing now).

Comment: I know in the recent version the missing topics fatal is false which works fine with the listener is starting and fails with `IllegalStateException`. Is it possible to throw similar exception when the listener is running but topic no longer exists  ? Appreciate the reply.

Comment: No, but I don't think you can delete a topic while there is an active consumer.